# VBA, Error 9 Wheres the error?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub NapiMaker()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Debug.Print wb.Name

    Dim MyFile As String

    If MyFile = "" Then
        MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
        Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
        wb.Activate

        Dim WS_Count As Integer
        Dim I As Integer

        WS_Count = wb.Worksheets.Count
        For I = 1 To WS_Count
            wb.Worksheets(I).Range("B7").Copy Workbooks(MyFile).Worksheets(1).Range("A16")
            wb.Worksheets(I).Range("B8").Copy Workbooks(MyFile).Worksheets(1).Range("B16")
            wb.Worksheets(I).Range("B10").Copy Workbooks(MyFile).Worksheets(1).Range("D16")
            wb.Worksheets(I).Range("B11").Copy Workbooks(MyFile).Worksheets(1).Range("J16")

            wb.Worksheets(I).Range("B5").Copy Workbooks(MyFile).Worksheets(1).Range("F16")
            wb.Worksheets(I).Range("B14").Copy Workbooks(MyFile).Worksheets(1).Range("E16")
            Workbooks(MyFile).Worksheets("1").Range("A16").EntireRow.Insert
        Next I
    End If

End Sub
```

I want to the the following:
 - I open a file.
 - Press CRTL+K.
 - Lets me choose a file.
 - Copy the specified cells to the chosen file.

I can't find the problem.
It's under the `For` loop

Comment: Which specific line is causing the error?  (I'm guessing it is `Workbooks(MyFile).Worksheets("1").Range("A16").EntireRow.Insert`, but please confirm.)  (And I'm voting to close as "typographical error" - I'll retract the close vote if you tell me it's a different line.)

Comment: there's no need to `Activate` the `wb`

Comment: No the wb.Worksheets(I).Range("B7").Copy Workbooks(MyFile).Worksheets(1).Range("A16")

I want to insert entire rows after a copy because i have 4 excels to copy with different nums of sheets @YowE3K

Comment: OK - I have no idea why that line would cause an error 9.  The only error 9 generating line I can see is due to the typo on the line I mentioned earlier.  (I will retract my close vote.)

Comment: No - I do have one more idea - what is the name of the file you opened, and what name is that file shown as having within Excel.  (Certain characters aren't supported if I remember correctly, and there are also size limitations.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filename passed as an index to the `Workbooks` collection appears to not allow the path to be included. (I was sure I had seen somewhere that it could be.)  Therefore `Workbooks("abcdef.xlsx")` would work, but `Workbooks("C:\Temp\abcdef.xlsx")` will not.

The following code will assign a `Workbook` object to the opened workbook, and then use that object to refer to it in subsequent statements, therefore avoiding the need to use an index into the `Workbooks` collection.

```
Sub NapiMaker()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wb1 As Workbook

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Debug.Print wb.Name

    Dim MyFile As String

    If MyFile = "" Then ' myFile will always be blank at this point
        MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
        Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)

        Dim WS_Count As Integer
        Dim I As Integer

        WS_Count = wb.Worksheets.Count
        For I = 1 To WS_Count
            wb.Worksheets(I).Range("B7").Copy wb1.Worksheets(1).Range("A16")
            wb.Worksheets(I).Range("B8").Copy wb1.Worksheets(1).Range("B16")
            wb.Worksheets(I).Range("B10").Copy wb1.Worksheets(1).Range("D16")
            wb.Worksheets(I).Range("B11").Copy wb1.Worksheets(1).Range("J16")
            wb.Worksheets(I).Range("B5").Copy wb1.Worksheets(1).Range("F16")
            wb.Worksheets(I).Range("B14").Copy wb1.Worksheets(1).Range("E16")

            'Changed "1" to 1
            wb1.Worksheets(1).Range("A16").EntireRow.Insert
        Next I
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Reaper - my code will only have fixed an error 9 at the line you said was causing the problem if you had something weird in the filename.  If you tell us what the filename is, we might be able to tell you why it caused problems.

Comment: No, i didn't change it.

Comment: It's "RÁDIÓ-ADATÁTVITEL-ÓRA-ITV 04 16" @YowE3K

Comment: @Reaper Hmmm - I was sure that I had seen somewhere that the file path could be included in the filename used as an index to `Workbooks`, but it appears it can't be.  So that means that the problem was simply that you hadn't stripped the path out of the filename.

Comment: Thank you! Have a nice day! @YowE3K